# What tools do you use to troubleshoot a slow-running SQL Server Report?

Tags: sql, windows, performance, reporting-services, monitoring

I'm a sys engineer for an Windows environment used by a `SQL Server reporting services` report developer. The developer uses a Win 7 dev box with `Visual Studio` to develop reports. The `SQL database` and `SQL report server` utilized by the developer are both hosted on a second Win 2012 server machine.

The developer tells me that when they are in the `VS IDE` developing reports and it comes time to run the report, it takes an unexpectedly long time (minutes) to run and display the results

I've looked at the high-level performance graphs for both machines and although both are getting a workout (e.g., 50% CPU), neither are anywhere near maxed out. So, I'm trying to draw a bead on a tool/s I can apply to try and spot where the problem is at a lower level (database, network, VS, report code). I've looked over [Performance Monitoring and Tuning Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/performance-monitoring-and-tuning-tools?view=sql-server-2017) but nothing stands out regarding this particular problem.

Is there a performance monitoring tool specifically used to troubleshooting a slow-running SQL Server Report?

Comment: Initially check the report execution log. Check report time columns to see what causes the delay. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @niktrs: Looks like a good place to start. Please add as answer.

Comment: Just let me know if you need more information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially check the report execution log.

Check report time columns to find what causes the delay.

For more information about report execution log:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-2017